# Unable to create a constant value of type. While trying to match data from viewmodel to context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im trying to get selected devices from view and match them with the devices in context but i only get the following:

> Unable to create a constant value of type **ViewModels.XXXViewModel**. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

```
public ActionResult TransferDevices(IList<XXXViewModel> viewModel)
{
    var selected = viewModel.Where(x => x.isSelected).ToList();
    IQueryable<Device> devicesQueryable = _db.Devices;

    var devices = devicesQueryable.Where(x => selected.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)).ToList() ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you should make `selected` a list of IDs... then you can just use `Contains`:

```
public ActionResult TransferDevices(IList<XXXViewModel> viewModel)
{
    var selected = viewModel.Where(x => x.isSelected)
                            .Select(x => x.Id)
                            .ToList();
    IQueryable<Device> devicesQueryable = _db.Devices;

    var devices = devicesQueryable.Where(x => selected.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
}
```

I'd *expect* that to work... it's certainly easier for the LINQ provider to translate.